# Porque este codigo no funciona?

Tags: python

```
a1 = c1 = a2 = c2 = a3 = c3 = 0
binario1 = input("Introduce el primer numero binario:")
binario2 = input("Introduce el segundo numero binario:")
x1 = int(binario1[0])
x2 = int(binario1[1])
y1 = int(binario2[0])
y2 = int(binario2[1])
if x1 + y1 == 0:
    a1 = 0
    c1 = 0
if x1 + y1 == 1:
    a1 = 1
    c1 = 0
if x1 + y1 == 2:
    a1 = 0
    c1 = 1

if x2 + y2 + c1 == 0:
    a2 = 0
    c2 = 0
if x2 + y2 + c1 == 1:
    a2 = 1
    c2 = 0
if x2 + y2 + c1 == 2:
    a2 = 0
    c2 = 1
if x2 + y2 + c1 == 3:
    a2 = 1
    c2 = 1

c2 = a3

if a3 == 1:
    print(a3, a2, a1, sep='')

if a3 == 0:
    print(a2, a1, sep='')
```

He realizado este codigo en python para sumar dos numeros binarios sin emplear bin(). Sin embargo, no funciona puesto que no devuelve el resultado deseado y no se cual es el error que he cometido. Seria de gran ayuda si alguien me ayudase a identificarlo. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Y te ponen restricciones? ¿Puedes usar listas, for, while, etc.?

Comment: no, tan solo que no debo usar las funciones bin().Porque?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado? ¿Cuál es el resultado actual? Pulsa en [edit] y agrega esos detalles, y modifica el título de la pregunta.

Comment: Creo que tu error es que la parte en que se hace la suma está suponiendo que x1 y1 son los bits menos significativos (los de la derecha), pero en realidad, ya que los has iniciado con el índice `[0]` de la cadena leida, son los más significativos (los de la izquierda). Fuera de eso tu código debería funcionar, pero es demasiado rígido ya que sólo vale para sumar números de dos bits y extenderlo a más bits se convierte en una pesadilla de código repetitivo. Para eso están los bucles.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está complicado tu código. Intente corregirlo, pero quedó horrible. Te ofrezco otra solución, que tal vez tu profesor apruebe:

Esta función recibe dos números binarios de cualquier largo en formato string y retorna su suma (en formato string).

```
def sumar_binario(bin1, bin2):
    b1 = bin1[-1::-1]
    b2 = bin2[-1::-1]
    suma = []
    carry = 0
    for digitos in itertools.zip_longest(b1, b2,fillvalue='0'):
        resultado = int(digitos[0]) + int(digitos[1]) + carry
        if resultado > 1:
            carry = 1
            resultado = 1 if resultado > 2 else 0
        suma.append(str(resultado))

    if carry:
        suma.append('1')

    return ''.join(suma[-1::-1])
```

La idea es recibir los binarios como "100" y "110" e invertirlos para recorrerlos fácilmente en orden creciente. Eso lo hago con comprensión de listas:

```
    b1 = bin1[-1::-1]
    b2 = bin2[-1::-1]
```

Entonces ahora tengo

```
b1 = "001"
b2 = "011"
```

Del paquete `itertools` uso la función `zip_longest` que toma dos iterables y me los devuelve como tuplas, tomando un elemento de cada iterable. Si un iterable es más corto, se rellena con el `fillvalue`, que es cero en este caso.

```
    for digitos in itertools.zip_longest(b1, b2,fillvalue='0'):
```

me va ir retornando `(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 2)`

En cada iteración todos los dos digitos binarios más el `carry` y los sumo. El resultado sólo puede ser 0, 1, 2 o 3.

Si el resultado es mayor que 1, pongo el `carry` en 1 y luego veo que dejar como resultado en esta posición. Si el resultado es 2, dejo 0, y si es 3, dejo 1.

Terminado esto, agrego `resultado` a la lista en construcción y procedo a la siguiente iteración.

Finalmente, tomo la lista con el resultado, la invierto con comprensión de lista y aplico `join` para juntar todo en un string.

#### Demo

```
import itertools

def sumar_binario(bin1, bin2):
    b1 = bin1[-1::-1]
    b2 = bin2[-1::-1]
    suma = []
    carry = 0
    for digitos in itertools.zip_longest(b1, b2,fillvalue='0'):
        resultado = int(digitos[0]) + int(digitos[1]) + carry
        if resultado > 1:
            carry = 1
            resultado = 1 if resultado > 2 else 0
        suma.append(str(resultado))

    if carry:
        suma.append('1')

    return ''.join(suma[-1::-1])

tests = [
    ("00", "00"),
    ("01", "01"),
    ("01", "10"),
    ("01", "11"),
    ("11", "01"),
    ("11", "10"),
    ("11", "11"),
    ("1000", "1111111111")
]

for test in tests:
    suma = sumar_binario(test[0], test[1])
    print(test[0], "+", test[1], "=", suma)
```

produce:

```
00 + 00 = 00
01 + 01 = 110
01 + 10 = 11
01 + 11 = 100
11 + 01 = 100
11 + 10 = 101
11 + 11 = 110
1000 + 1111111111 = 10000000111

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: @Alvaro no digas gracias.. en su lugar, acepta la respuesta si te sirvio.. Lee los enlaces que deje en tu pregunta.. la forma de decir gracias es aceptando la respuesta...